# Deleting a column in dataframe using function

Tags: r

It's seems to me that I don't understand something about functions in R.
Suppose we have a simple dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(3, 4))
```

One can delete column using for example this way:

```
 df$A <- NULL
```

I tried to wrap it up into function and unaccountably it wouldn't work:

```
delete_col <- function(df) {
  df$A <- NULL
}
delete_col(df)
```

Could anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delete_col <- function(df) {
    df$A <- NULL
    return(df)
}
delete_col(df)
```

This will give the result you are looking for. If you want to keep the changes to df, then use `df<-delete_col(df)`

Your function does not output anything. Your function deletes the column from df, but it never outputs the resulting dataframe. By using `return(df)` you are giving the function something to output, `df`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this isn't working is because you are actually deleting a column from a parameter variable which is just a copy of the actual data frame you passed into the function.  If you want the column deletion to "stick," you can use the parent scope assignment operator (`<<-`):

```
delete_col <- function(df) {
    df$A <<- NULL
}
delete_col(df)
```

By using `<<-` instead of `<-`, R will make the assignment to the data frame in the parent scope, which is whence you called the function, and hence the column will be deleted when the function returns.

Comment: First time I come across the <<- operator. Good to know that such a thing exists.